# I am creating a predator-prey simulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation

This is my current code

```
#this is the input for population and predators
popOne=float(input("Enter the predator population : "))  20

popTwo=float(input("Enter the prey population :")) 1000

#period is the amount of iterations, in my case 10
period=float(input("Enter the number of periods: ")) 10

#This is the values for the given periods
A=float(input("Enter the value .1: ")) .1
B=float(input("Enter the value .01 : ")) .01
C=float(input("Enter the value .01 : ")) .01
D=float(input("Enter the value .00002: ")) .00002

#Formluas from my book for prey population, and predator population

prey=(popTwo*(1+A-(B*popOne)))

pred=(popOne*(1-C+(D*popTwo)))

i=0
for i in range(10):
    print(prey)
    print(pred)
    i = i+1
```

This last part is where I am having my error. I cannot get the code to print out the first iteration and proceed to the second, third, so on.

Also, how might I make the output look like:

```
After period 1 there are 20 predators
After period 1 there are 900 prey

After period 2 there are 20 predators
After period 2 there are 808 prey 

After period 3 there are 20 predators
After period 3 there are 724 prey
```

And so on.

Comment: Why do you ask the user to enter specific values instead of just setting them? And what output do you actually want? The problem you're trying to solve is unclear.

Comment: The problem in the book asks for the program to prompt the user. Because it could be change to different values.

Comment: The problem im having is it prints 900prey,20predators 10 times. And I need it to take the first input, move to the second, move to the third from the previous result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your population updating code inside your loop. I also suggest using the `pred` and `prey` variables for the starting populations too. Here's some code:

```
pred = float(input("Enter the predator population : ")) # use pred and prey here
prey = float(input("Enter the prey population :"))

periods = int(input("Enter the number of periods: "))

A=float(input("Enter the value .1: ")) # these should have better prompts
B=float(input("Enter the value .01 : "))
C=float(input("Enter the value .01 : "))
D=float(input("Enter the value .00002: "))

for i in range(periods):
   # update both pred and prey at once (so no temp vars are needed)
   # also, lots of unneeded parentheses were removed
   prey, pred = prey*(1 + A - B*pred), pred*(1 - C + D*prey)

   print("After period {} there are {:.0f} predators, and {:.0f} prey"
         .format(i, pred, prey))
```

Comment: Could you possibly explain to me how the {} works inside a print statement and also why you used both {:.of} and the .format(I,pred,prey)

Comment: Each `{}` in the format string indicates a place to put one of the arguments to `format` (you can specify which argument in various ways, like `{0}` to substitute the first positional argument, or `{foo}` to substitute in a keyword named "foo"). You can also (optionally) provide some extra formatting guidance after a colon character. The `0f` code specifies that the formatting for the two populations (which are floating point values) should be truncated to zero-decimal places (this is the `.0`), and only shown in scientific notation if they are very large (the `f`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but I feel like the lines that assign values to prey & pred should be inside your loop?

I also think the formulas that calculate the values of prey & pred would use the current values of prey & pred, not the initial values entered by the user?

Comment: so given the prompt to input prey,predator values. The amount of periods or iterations(10).Then print the populations for the given number of periods. With the inputs from a b c and d.

Answer (score 0):

Numerous problems with your code:

1. `period` should be read as an integer, and should probably be used
   to control the range of your loop.
2. `i` is set and updated by the loop, don't try to initialize it or
   update it manually.
3. The formulas for `pred` and `prey` need to be applied in every
   iteration of the loop, i.e., move them into the loop prior to the
   print statements.  They should also be `int`'ed.
4. After calculating `pred` and `prey`, you need to update the
   population values `popOne` and `popTwo` accordingly.
5. You should change your prompts from `"Enter the value .1: "` to
   something more informative and general such as `"Enter the value for coefficient
   A: "`.

Answer (score 0):

## THIS SIMPLE CODE WILL SHOW A PREDATOR PREY MODEL

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

## POPULATION DATA

```
print "Enter the population of the prey:"
prey = float(input());

print "Enter the population of the predator:"
pred = float(input());

print "Enter Simulation Time in seconds:"
simulation_time = int(input())

time = 0.0
t = []
dt = 0.05

A = .1
B = .01
C = .01
D = 0.00002


while time < simulation_time:
    prey = (prey*(1+A-(B*pred)))
    pred=(pred*(1-C+(D*prey)))
    time = time +dt

print("After {} seconds there are {:.0f} predators, and {:.0f} prey" .format(simulation_time, pred, prey))
```

Comment: You should add some explanation about what your code is doing and how it is different from the OP's code.